# Plumbing through wall that rests on joist

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, framing

My new construction home had the option of adding a 3rd floor bathroom that I declined at the time, but now would like to pursue. Luckily, the builder already ran plumbing and electrical in the area to easily allow for this to be done in the future.

I already have the bathroom framed and now that I'm looking to get the plumbing rough-in done, I'm realizing some potential issues. My 2x4 walls are framed directly over floor joists, so there's no way to route the drain pipe up through the wall without eating into a chunk of the floor joist, which I'm assuming could cause issues for me at inspection time.

In hindsight I probably should have used wider framing to allow adequate room for plumbing along where the vanity and toilet will go. Rather than redo this entire wall, I'm wondering if an easier solution might be to essentially frame up a parallel wall with 2x4s, bringing the total wall thickness to 7" which would be more than enough for my plumbing and allow for me to punch into from below without compromising my joist, and similarly avoid the ceiling joists for running my vent pipe.

The bathroom is currently 69" wide so losing 3-1/2" for this is not a big deal. I'm just wondering if this is a proper solution and whether it might raise any eyebrows come inspection time. [image]

Comment: You can always run it by the inspectors.

Comment: I'm not even sure how I'd do that as there's no straightforward way to contact them outside of making an online scheduling request. I think the county is pretty slammed right now so thus far they've been unresponsive to other questions I've had.

If not for the fact that I've already ran electrical, I'd just redo the wall with 2x6 or 2x8 studs. I really don't want to have to replace the existing wall as wiring for outlets, fan, and vanity lighting already passes through it, which has already been inspected and signed off.

Comment: I don't see any reason offhand that a double wall would be forbidden.  Double walls with voids in the middle are used for architectural or soundproofing reasons, and double walls tight together with staggered studs can be used to improve insulation.  Equally reasonable would be to build one around a duct, chimney, or plumbing.

Comment: @Danny if you're also 'dan' the OP, you should merge your accounts so you can take ownership of this post and replies. Check out the Help link for more information.

Comment: @FredricShope yes I am OP, unfortunately I encountered some kind of edge case with the site where I was able to "post as guest" with an email account that was already registered. I hit an error when I try to merge, probably because they are the same email address.

Comment: I'm not sure how much extra wire there and how the wall is connected at the top but is there a way you could shimmy the wall in enough to drill a hole for the lines to go through?  Have 1/2 of the wall on the beam, 1/2 overhanging?